# NameError: name 'build' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to write a python script to fetch entries from a google calendar.

I am getting a `NameError: name 'build' is not defined` for the line below:

`service = build('calendar','v3',credentials=credentials)`

Are there any suggestions for how to fix this?

Comment: Where do you believe the interpreter finds it? Your only import statement is selective in that you only import `InstalledAppFlow` to the global namespace.

Comment: Not sure, do I have to include a statement to import build to the global namespace?

Comment: where is `build` imported or defined? the script is telling you, you're calling a function that has not been defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Python Quickstart for Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) as reference.

Notice in the import section which module the build method was derived from:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build //notice the build here
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import datetime
```

before it was used here:

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from apiclient import discovery
...
credentials = flow.run_console()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
```